# Dismiss requested topic as 'Already exists' does not allow to select an existing topic request as a reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

It only allows selecting existing **topics**.

However if a similar **topic request** has already been made, I think this should count as a duplicate as well, as I do not see why there should be multiple requests for the same thing.

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, you can post a comment with the link and dismiss as "is not necessary".

Comment: This should work in the next build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for this has been added, and should work after the next deploy (probably some point later today)